# Recalculate Normal Vector without rotation matrix

Tags: geometry

I have 3 points in 3 dimensions (P0, P1, P2) and a normalised vector N1, that lies on the plane constructed by those points and is perpendicular to the line P0-P1.

I want to find the normal vector N2 perpendicular to the line P0-P2, lying on the same plane and facing the same direction as N1.

I think i know how to construct N2 by calculating the angle at P0, creating a rotation matrix and transforming N1 accordingly.

But is it possible to construct N2 using simple operations like dot or cross product, without calculating and using the angle?

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhF28.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector $n_2$ can be expressed as
$$n_2=\alpha (P_1-P_0)+\beta(P_2-P_0).$$

Solving
$$
n_2\cdot(P_2-P_0) = 0,\\
n_2\cdot n_2 = 1,
$$
with condition $n_2\cdot n_1 \ge 0$, will give you $\alpha,\beta$.

Alternatively, you can construct $((P_2-P_0)\times (P_1-P_0))\times(P_2-P_0)$, normalize it and invert if $n_1\cdot n_2<0$.

Comment: Blazing fast, Thank you! I have to admit that i don't understand the first solution (calculating ,). The alternative is what i was hoping for.